# Cannot Collide in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to make pin pon game, one rectangle is right side of the screen and other one is left side of the screen of course. When the ball hits the second rectangle it needs to be collide but in the update method there is a hits1 variable which supposed to be  collide the stuffs but in same line

```py
hits1 = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player,self.balls,False)
```

pygame gives me this error:

> AttributeError: 'pygame.math.Vector2' object has no attribute 'colliderect'

```
import pygame as pg
import random
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from os import path


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize game window, etc
        pg.init()
        pg.mixer.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.running = True


def new(self):
    # start a new game
    self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.balls = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.player = Player(self)
    self.player2 = Player2(self)
    self.ball = Ball(self.player.pos.x + 10, self.player.pos.y + 20,self)
    self.all_sprites.add(self.player,self.player2)
    self.all_sprites.add(self.ball)
    self.balls.add(self.ball)
    self.run()

def run(self):
    # Game Loop
    self.playing = True
    while self.playing:
        self.clock.tick(FPS)
        self.events()
        self.update()
        self.draw()

def update(self):
    # Game Loop - Update
    self.all_sprites.update()
    hits1 = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player,self.balls,False)

    if hits1:
        self.player2.throw_back()

def events(self):
    # Game Loop - events
    for event in pg.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            if self.playing:
                self.playing = False
            self.running = False



def draw(self):
    # Game Loop - draw
    self.screen.fill(BLACK)
    self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pg.display.flip()

def show_start_screen(self):
    # game splash/start screen
    pass

def show_go_screen(self):
    # game over/continue
    pass




g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while g.running:
    g.new()
    g.show_go_screen()

pg.quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't show all relevant code but my educated guess is somewhere you have a `Sprite` class (either `Player` and/or `Ball`) where you assing a `Vector2` instance to the `rect` attribute instead of a `Rect` instance.

I don't know how the code actually looks like but instead of something like this:

```
self.rect = some_vector
```

alter the existing `Rect` like this instead:

```
self.rect.topleft = some_vector
```